# DefaultParser in Apache Commons CLI

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons

I wanted to try out the Apache Commons CLI, and figured a good place to start would be the 'usage' section on its web page.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html

Now, the example suggest to create a `DefaultParser`, however the closest sounding I could find is `BasicParser`. Is this the thing to use, am I missing something?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I used `GnuParser()` instead of `DefaultParser()` and it works well.

`CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();`

Update : In version 1.3.1 of CLI, `GnuParser()` is now deprecated. So I simply added 
`import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;`
and now I use `CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();`
And all is fine!

Answer (score 13):

What version of CLI are you using? DefaultParser wasn't added until the 1.3 snapshot.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/DefaultParser.html

Comment: but maven has till 1.2 only. when will maven get 1.3-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Where do you find the 1.3-Snapshot for download?

Answer (score 10):

I've encountered the same problem while following [same usage guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html) with commons-cli 1.2 and found the following available parsers:

- `org.apache.commons.cli.BasicParser`
- `org.apache.commons.cli.GnuParser`
- `org.apache.commons.cli.PosixParser`

They all extends the org.apache.commons.cli.Parser and only implement the `flatten` method. You can check [Parser's javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/cli/Parser.html) (and implementing parsers) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

this DefaultParser class is of Apache CLI 1.3 so for using this you have to update your class path with jar varsion 1.3